# EditFor does not change value for model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I've got a main view and some partial views. My model has a list of objects and I iterate over the list and each element is sent to partial view. 
I use BeginForm on my main view and so far after submiting on main form I've managed to aquire my list of objects but in their starting state. 
I've got a textbox which should change one of my properties for the element from the list but it seems to not work.

Here is some code
My main view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRecruitmentActivities", "RecruitmentActivities", FormMethod.Post))
 {
@model MonthlyRecruitmentActivity

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.HoursLeft, new { id = "hoursLeftHidden" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Title)

for (int i = 0; i < Model.Activities.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Activities[i].File)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Activities[i].HoursDone)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Activities[i].Id)
}

<div>

                @foreach (var activity in Model.Activities)
                {                      
                    @Html.Partial("_recruitmentActivityComponent", activity)
                }

 <div><button type="submit" style="margin: 15px" id="saveDocBtn" value="Zatw_1" class="editButton" />Save</div>
</div>
}
```

My partial:

```
@model  RecruitmentActivityComponent
div class="col-md-2" style="font-size: smaller">
                    <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.HoursDone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })</div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.HoursDone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control countable" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.HoursDone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The models:

```
public class MonthlyRecruitmentActivity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int HoursLeft { get; set; }
        public RecruitmentActivityComponent[] Activities { get; set; }
    }

public class RecruitmentActivityComponent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "errr msg")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "error msg")]
    [Display(Name = "Text")]
    public int HoursDone { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say at first I had an element of type RecruitmentActivityComponent with  HoursDone set to 0, I've changed it to 5 and sent to my controller. My controller still sees the 0.

Comment: have you tried changing `Model` to `model` on this statement `@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.HoursDone, new {})` ?

Comment: after changing it to  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoursDone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control countable" } })  still the same problem

Comment: @Josh  I've also corrected this line (and two more) to have "model" instead of "Model" as well like this    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Activities[i].HoursDone))